# Selenium RC - How to open two firefox browsers simultaneously

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-server

In selenium RC, can we run 2 test simultaneously in different browser window of same browser (Say Firefox) in one machine?

Understanding the concept of selenium server, please clarify whether we can create two sessions in a machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run two tests simultaneously. You should start the RC server on different ports.
Maybe this article helps you:
http://www.zacharyfox.com/blog/testing/selenium-rc-multiple-users

Comment: Can you post at least the main points from the linked site? Links often go down, at which point this answer becomes unusable. See [answer].